# Build And Archive Buttons Don't Do Anything in XCode 3.2.4 for me

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, ios

After I use Build and Archive to produce an Ad Hoc Distribution build, the Organizer appears. When I select the build, and press Share Application, the dialog pops up, but thereafter none of the buttons work. I can't Distribute For Enterprise, Save To Disk or Email. I press the buttons and they just pop right back up.

There are no errors or warnings on the archive build.

Anyone else have this happen and have a fix? Much appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact problem:  the Share and Email buttons which normally worked have stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed multiple copies xcode?  The order of installation matters.

Install the most recent version of xcode last.  The older versions will still work, but the newer install needs it's version of the system files.

*(I typically put the latest version in Developer (and earlier versions in Develeoper 3.2 etc..)*

**How to Troubleshoot this:**

Check the OSX Console.app and view your system.log

My system.log shows the error: it was referencing this "other" version of xcode:

```
- sh: /Developer: is a directory - /Developer 3.2/usr/bin/xcodebuild fails with 32256
```

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: Yep, I see the same problem. In my case because XCode 4 installs in /Xcode4, and I'd removed it to save space. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you selecting a valid Distribution Provision profile?  You have to attempt to "share" using a valid profile (from the drop-down above the buttons) to get it push out the .iap.

I don't think Distribute for Enterprise works unless your dev Id is associated with an Enterprise Class DEV license. (could be wrong about that one though)